Continuously compile multiple configurations in sbt
I can execute multiple tasks with IT/compile; Test/compile in sbt shell but how to run it continuously?
~IT/compile; ~Test/compile fails because it starts them separately:
Tried to start new watch while channel, 'console0', was already watching 'IT/compile; ~Test/compile'


Doesn't the integration testing configuration extend the test configuration? If so, ~IT/compile should already continuously compile everything you need.

For the sake of exercise let's assume it doesn't (I want to do this some other configs as well)
